# Perl on Hash and Array References

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I have a csv file, `transcation.csv`, which looks like this:

```
TransactionID,Date,AccNum,Type,Amt  
657520,02-07-1999,016901581432,Debit,16000  
657524,02-07-1999,016901581432,Debit,13000  
657538,09-07-1999,016901581432,Credit,11000  
657548,18-07-1999,016901581432,Credit,15500  
657519,02-07-1999,016901581433,Debit,12000  
657523,02-07-1999,016901581433,Credit,11000  
657529,03-07-1999,016901581433,Debit,15000  
657539,10-07-1999,016901581433,Credit,10000  
657541,11-07-1999,016901581434,Debit,12000  
657525,03-07-1999,016901581434,Debit,15000  
657533,05-07-1999,016901581434,Credit,12500
```

I am supposed to read the data from `transaction.csv` and store it in a hash. And then pass the hash and list of Account numbers to the function, and then make the function to calculate total Debit Amount and Credit Amount of the listed accounts using the data in the hash.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %banks;
&arrhas_banks(\%banks);
my @accnum = qw(016901581432 016901581434);
hasarr_banks(\%banks,\@accnum);

sub arrhas_banks
{
  my $banks = shift;
  open(FH,"<transaction.csv") or die "Could not open 'transaction.csv' $!\n";
  while (my $data=<FH>) 
  {
    chomp($data);
    my @records = split ",", $data;
    $banks->{$records[0]} =
      { 'AccNum' => $records[2], 'Type' => $records[3], 'Amt' => $records[4] };
  }
  close(FH);
}

sub hasarr_banks {
  my ($banks, $accnum) = @_;
  foreach my $id (keys %{$banks}) {
    my $answer;
    foreach my $num (@{$accnum}) {
      if($banks->{$id}{'AccNum'} == $num) {
        $answer = 1;
      }
    }
    if($answer) {
      my $type = $banks->{$id}{'Type'};
      $total{$accnum}{$type} += $banks->{$id}{'Amt'};
    }
  }
  foreach my $no (@{$accnum}} { 
    print "Debit amount of $no is $total{$accnum}{'Debit'}";
    print "Credit amount of $no is $tot{$accnum}{'Credit'}";
  }
}
```

I am supposed to produce output like this:

```
Debit amount of 016901581432 is 29000  
Credit amount of 016901581432 is 26500  
Debit amount of 016901581434 is 27000  
Credit amount of 016901581434 is 12500
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
Debit amount of 016901581432 is 56000    
Credit amount of 016901581432 is 39000  
Debit amount of 016901581434 is 56000  
Credit amount of 016901581434 is 39000
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %banks;
&arrhas_banks(\%banks);
my @accnum = qw(016901581432 016901581434);
hasarr_banks(\%banks,\@accnum);

sub arrhas_banks
{
  my $banks = shift;
  open(FH,"<transaction.csv") or die "Could not open 'transaction.csv' $!\n";
  while (my $data=<FH>) 
  {
    chomp($data);
    my @records = split ",", $data;
    $banks->{$records[0]} =
      { 'AccNum' => $records[2], 'Type' => $records[3], 'Amt' => $records[4] };
  }
  close(FH);
}

sub hasarr_banks {
  my ($banks, $accnum) = @_;
  foreach my $id (keys %{$banks}) {
    my $answer;
    foreach my $num (@{$accnum}) {
      if($banks->{$id}{'AccNum'} == $num) {
        $answer = 1;
      }
    }
    if($answer) {
      my $type = $banks->{$id}{'Type'};
      $total{ $banks->{$id}{'AccNum'} }->{$type} += $banks->{$id}{'Amt'};
    }
  }
  foreach my $no (@{$accnum}) { 
    print "Debit amount of $no is $total{$accnum}{'Debit'}";
    print "Credit amount of $no is $total{$accnum}{'Credit'}";
  }
}
```

No output yet. Still going wrong?

Comment: Some of your code has syntax errors -- for example, `foreach my $no (@{$accnum}} {` should be `foreach my $no (@{$accnum}) {` -- so is it fair to assume that this is not the exact code that you ran?

Comment: @ruakh He declared `accnum` as an array so shouldn't it be `foreach my $no (@accunm)`?

Comment: @squiguy No, he has a global `@accnum` and a lexical `$accnum.` Presumably he means the latter.

Comment: @TLP Didn't catch that, but you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are double counting.

This code is broken in 2 places:

1. First, Since your AccNum in your sample data is ALWAYS one of the 2 accounts in `$accnum` list, $answer will ALWAYS be 1.

   foreach my $num (@{$accnum}) {
          if($banks->{$id}{'AccNum'} == $num) {
               $answer = 1;
          }
       }
2. Second, you are assigning to `$total` based on `$accnum` key - BUT, `$accnum` is an array reference to a list of account #s - take a look at your subroutine call.

   In other words, your `$total` hashref will ONLY have one key, looking like "ARRAY(SOMETHING)" instead of 2 keys one for each account #.

What you need to do is simply assign to correct account #:

```
if ($answer) {
  my $type = $banks->{$id}{'Type'};
  $total{ $banks->{$id}{'AccNum'} }->{$type} += $banks->{$id}{'Amt'};
}
```

A an aside, your code style is not very good as far as readability. Not the worst I've seen but definitely not close to ideal.

Comment: But can you tell me what is the change i am supposed to do in the printing part?

Comment: You need to print `$total{$no}{'Debit'}` and `$total{$no}{'Credit'}`.

Comment: I am not getting output for the changes I made in the script which I showed first

Answer (score 3):

You should try using a csv module, such as [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV). Note in the below example that the `DATA` file handle can be replaced with any IO input handle.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use feature 'say';

my $c = Text::CSV->new( );                    # default settings are ok
$c->column_names( $c->getline(*DATA) );       # set headers
my %acc;

while (my $row = $c->getline_hr(*DATA)) {     # $row is a hash ref
    if ($row->{Type} eq "Debit") {
        $acc{ $row->{AccNum} }{Debit}  += $row->{Amt};
    } elsif ($row->{Type} eq "Credit") {
        $acc{ $row->{AccNum} }{Credit} += $row->{Amt};
    } else { warn "Bad csv line '@$row'" }    # precaution
}

for my $acc (keys %acc) {
    say "Debit amount of $acc is ", $acc{$acc}{Debit};
    say "Credit amount of $acc is ", $acc{$acc}{Credit};
}

__DATA__
TransactionID,Date,AccNum,Type,Amt
657520,02-07-1999,016901581432,Debit,16000  
657524,02-07-1999,016901581432,Debit,13000  
657538,09-07-1999,016901581432,Credit,11000  
657548,18-07-1999,016901581432,Credit,15500  
657519,02-07-1999,016901581433,Debit,12000  
657523,02-07-1999,016901581433,Credit,11000  
657529,03-07-1999,016901581433,Debit,15000  
657539,10-07-1999,016901581433,Credit,10000  
657541,11-07-1999,016901581434,Debit,12000  
657525,03-07-1999,016901581434,Debit,15000  
657533,05-07-1999,016901581434,Credit,12500
```

**Output:**

```
Debit amount of 016901581433 is 27000
Credit amount of 016901581433 is 21000
Debit amount of 016901581434 is 27000
Credit amount of 016901581434 is 12500
Debit amount of 016901581432 is 29000
Credit amount of 016901581432 is 26500
```